# How to get specific row from Dataset in RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have three textboxes. Each text box will show a value which get from first row, second row and third row of "MyDataset" Dataset.

My Dataset contain about these

```
 ____SEQ_NO____|____USER__
      1        |  Beckham
      2        |  Cantona
      3        |   Depay
```

So I created hidden tablix for binding Dataset and get values from each cell.
My tablix include with

**ROW1 Column** for display USER from **first row** of dataset

**ROW2 Column** for display USER from **second row** of dataset

**ROW3 Column** for display USER from **third row** of dataset

I try to use this expression for each Column.

**For ROW1**

```
        =Lookup(Fields!SEQ_NO.Value,1, Fields!USER.Value, "MyDataset")
```

**For ROW2**

```
        =Lookup(Fields!SEQ_NO.Value,2, Fields!USER.Value, "MyDataset")
```

**For ROW3**

```
        =Lookup(Fields!SEQ_NO.Value,3, Fields!USER.Value, "MyDataset")
```

But It's wrong. I don't understand. Why it show only first row like result below.

```
  _SEQ_NO___|___ROW1__|___ROW2__|___ROW3___
      1     | Beckham |         |  
      2     |         | Beckham |           
      3     |         |         |  Beckham
```

**###### My Expected Result should be like below. #####**

```
  _SEQ_NO___|___ROW1__|___ROW2__|___ROW3___
      1     | Beckham |         |  
      2     |         | Cantona |           
      3     |         |         |  Depay
```

If this is a correct. My three textbox can refer each specific row by this expression

```
 **For Textbox1**

         =ReportItems!ROW1.Value 

 **For Textbox2**

         =ReportItems!ROW2.Value 

 **For Textbox3**

         =ReportItems!ROW3.Value
```

Comment: Can you also show what is your expected result?

Comment: I edited for adding expected result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to switch your first two parameters of lookup function.

```
 =Lookup(1, Fields!SEQ_NO.Value, Fields!USER.Value, "MyDataset") 

 =Lookup(2, Fields!SEQ_NO.Value, Fields!USER.Value, "MyDataset")  

 =Lookup(3, Fields!SEQ_NO.Value, Fields!USER.Value, "MyDataset")
```

The way it was specified by you `=Lookup(Fields!SEQ_NO.Value,1,....` will cause it to return multiple values. That's why it was just showing the data from the first row.

Comment: Oh, I don't know before!! Thank you very much.